# Error: Cannot find module './Mime'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to get a heroku project running (following the tutorial [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs)) and I'm running into a bit of trouble.

The node task on Heroku is throwing the following:

```
app[web.1]:     module.js:540
app[web.1]:     throw err;
app[web.1]:     ^
app[web.1]:
app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './Mime'
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mime/index.js:3:12)
app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

I have installed (with -save) all of the dependencies I need including mime, but it seems like it's getting caught up with the mime module itself, here's the mime node_module:

```
         1,545 .eslintrc.json
<DIR>          .github
         9,230 CHANGELOG.md
           157 cli.js
           127 index.js
         1,098 LICENSE
           101 lite.js
         1,951 Mime.js
         2,824 package.json
         5,468 README.md
<DIR>          src
<DIR>          types
```

The mime/index.js file:

```
'use strict';

var Mime = require('./Mime');
module.exports = new Mime(require('./types/standard'), require('./types/other'));
```

and my project's dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "express-less": "^0.1.0",
    "express-minify": "^0.2.0",
    "favicon": "0.0.2",
    "helmet": "^2.3.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "logger": "0.0.1",
    "mime": "^2.0.3",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.11",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.4.1",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "^0.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you `git add` and `git commit` to your repo before Heroku deployment?

Comment: I ran `git add . -A` `git commit` `git push` (for my actual repo) and `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

Whelp, hard to say 100% what I did to fix the issue but it was probably one of the following things.

- I added `"engines": {"node": "7.5.0","npm": "4.1.2"}` to my node package (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version))
- I added a Procfile to the root with `web: node server.js` (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#define-a-procfile))

as a side note, caching was a big issue for me after I solved this issue.  [This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior) link may help with that.